# Requests timing out?

Tags: support, performance

I'm just wondering if I am the only one noticing this issue:

It seems that when I submit questions, answers, or comments, its VERY common for the page to time out indefinitely (but the question still gets submitted).

After making a comment/answer, the browser is just sitting and waiting.   However, after 5-10 seconds, I can just click the question title and see that my answer/comment was indeed added with no problems.

Does anyone else experience this?   I've noticed this at home, at work, and on my phone.   I've noticed this in Firefox, Chrome, and Opera (and webkit-based mobile browser).

Being that it happens under so many scenarios, I tend to think that the issue isn't on my end.

Is this a widespread problem or am I living in some sort of weird bizarro zone?

Comment: Can it get more bizarro than Michigan?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll chime in.

Quite often (several times each day) Stack Overflow seems to "forget" about me after I submit a post or a comment. I get the little *spinny* "I'm doing something now" icon and it just goes on and on for a few minutes or more until I refresh/close the tab or it just recovers on its own. Then everything is fine again.

It doesn't seem to be related to Stack Overflow performance because I just keep going in another tab and everything seems to be normal otherwise.  If I refresh the "busy" tab, my post seemed to get through just fine. I just assumed that whatever "*I'm-Done*" signal I'm supposed to get back from Stack Overflow is getting lost or stuck somewhere.

*I'm sure I read that Jeff acknowledged this "problem" somewhere here but I can't find a link to it. Maybe it was in one of the Podcasts.*

P.S. I'm currently using Firefox 3.5.2, but I'm pretty sure this isn't a recent problem. It never bothered me, though.

Comment: Yes, this is EXACTLY what I am talking about.   Seems to happen to me very often.

Answer (score 0):

*Usually* SO is very fast for me. Occasionally it's slow over 3G, but that's fair enough :)

Sometimes it becomes very slow for a while (5 minutes to an hour) - but usually that affects the whole site for me, not just posting. Different sites can be fast or slow independently, in my experience.

Comment: That's the thing, it's not like it loads slowly, it's that it just fails to reload at all after submissions.   When it doesn't fail to reload, everything is great.